# DC-DC buck converter using transistors

Tags: transistors, dc-dc-converter, buck

I found [this genius buck circuit with only 2 transistors.](https://www.romanblack.com/smps/smps.htm)

I don’t know how exactly it works and don’t know how to calculate the frequency or determine any parameters of the components.

What is the work flow of this circuit and the calculations?

[image]

Comment: A fairly good explanation at the end of the page: [SPOT THE MISTAKES! Page 13](http://talkingelectronics.com/projects/SpotMistakes/SpotMistakesP13.html)

Comment: And the [online discussion](https://www.electro-tech-online.com/threads/spotthemistake-critiques-roman-blacks-two-transistor-switcher-design.128790/) between designer, critiquer and community on circuit operation.  Search for "Mike said". <added RMc>

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat - I skimmed that page, and although I agreed with many comments, there were many I found to be over-critical. There are a few instances where he writes something to the effect of "I can't understand why X" or "Components Y & Z are unnecessary", when a little extra analysis of the circuit would clear that up. As an example , he writes "He never shows the high speed diode "flipping over" and conducting." when imo the original author's "Phase3: OFF" quite clearly shows the diode conducting. Overall I'd recommend taking "Spot the Mistakes" commentary with a handful of salt ...

Comment: @brhans I would normally say similate it.  I did not focus on critisms as much as the gist of the basic operation of circuit.

Comment: there's a difference between a science trick and a magic trick; the former has to be repeatable and useful to others. While anyone can play around and get lucky with a demo circuit, there's a reason general purpose SMPS drivers exist.

Comment: See addition to my answer - full description of operation by Roman Black himself. Link supplied by StainlessSteelRat.

Comment: @dandavis The circuit was developed by Roman with some care. It's unidealitoes and quirks are known and acknowledged by him. See my answer to a link to his descriptioon of operation. The circuit was developed as a response to a design challenge by me in 2001 :-). [Minimum parts count / max simplicity to meet well described requirements].

Answer (score 7):

Your circuit is a "Black Regulator" (named after it's creator Roman Black.
It  was the result of a design competition that I initiated on the PICList** in 2001. I had a very useful 3 transistor design and challenged people to built a simpler equally effective design. This was a friendly competition where no single design had to "win".
[Here is the original specification](http://www.piclist.com/techref/postbot.asp?by=thread&id=%5BEE%5D%3A+Design+Challenge+%2D+low+power+step+down+switc&w=body&tgt=post) - August 20th 2001. About 80 pages of discussion from various people. (Roman, & SE EE members Olin, Spehro, me, ...)

The Black regulator was the simplest design, but my "GSR"* was more useful in a wider range of cases.  The Black Regulator was based on a simplification of Richard Prosser's (brilliant) relay driver which maintained approximately constant relay coil  voltage for a wide range of applied voltages using the relay coil as the inductor. Roman simplified it and turned it into a general purpose buck regulator.

An extensive range of comments and descriptions can be found by searching the PICList archives and copies thereof or the internet in general. Index terms include "black regulator", "GSR", "God's Switching Regulator"*, 'Richard Prosser's relay driver'.

I can explain operation in detail if desired BUT try looking through the extensive on-web material first. I'd recommend "my" GSR design for anything but applications requiring the absolute minimum of parts (and then not by much).

Here is a [**full description of operation**](https://www.electro-tech-online.com/threads/spotthemistake-critiques-roman-blacks-two-transistor-switcher-design.128790/) **by Roman Black himself**.
Search on that page for: Mike said.
(Link supply by StainlessSteelRat).

Here are a few such other references:

[Richard Prosser's Relay Driver](http://www.massmind.org/Techref/io/relay/HVwLVcoil.htm) with circuit and explanation.  This is a superset of the Black Regulator.
and [Richard's original post](http://www.piclist.com/techref/postbot.asp?by=time&id=piclist%5C2001%5C08%5C26%5C170913a)

[Improvements suggested by Dave Dilatusch](http://www.piclist.com/techref/postbot.asp?by=time&id=piclist%5C2001%5C08%5C26%5C191843a)

[Original low cost buck challenge which Roman responded to](http://www.piclist.com/techref/postbot.asp?by=thread&id=%5BEE%5D%3A+Design+Challenge+%2D+low+power+step+down+switc&w=body&tgt=post) August 2001

[Your link](https://www.romanblack.com/smps/smps.htm)

[EEV Blog BR discussion](https://www.eevblog.com/forum/projects/negative-version-of-roman-black_s-two-transistor-discrete-buck-regulator/)

[Here](http://www.sxlist.com/techref/postbot.asp?by=thread&id=%25simple+step-up+SMPS+challenge%25&w=body&tgt=post) is a long and hopefully useful 20 year old thread where Roman Black and I and even Olin Lathrop and others discuss a step up challenge initiated by Roman. Much to learn there (including by me at the time :-) )_.

Includes this super horrible nasty really-does-work boost-converter circuit by me :-)

[image]

---

Similar to my GSR design. Published a few years after mine. May or may not be based on it. This (and mine) are in fact a well enough known "hysteretic converter". Output as shown is "chaotic" - which can be useful for low EM radiation. Efficiency and less chaotic operation can be improved with a whiff of added positive feedback. Discussed in various GSR threads. The link to this image is broken - I may be able to find one.

[image]

---

- "GSR" stands for "God's Switching Regulator" - there is an interesting story behind the name (as one may expect) but I won't add it here at this stage.

** PICLIST. Recommended. Good complement to SEEE - NOT a replacement - friendly discussion type mailing list. Vast cross section of experts. A number are also SE members.[Disclosure: I'm an admin].
[Intro](http://www.piclist.com/techref/piclist/index.htm) & [Join](http://mailman.mit.edu/mailman/listinfo/piclist)

Comment: Hi I have read the posts. but still confused how the capacitor works.

Comment: Hi I have read the posts. but still confused how C2works. when Q1 opens, the L1 starts to charge until it reaches Isat.  And at this moment, will the collector of Q1 become 0 due to di/dt = 0? what confused me is when Q1 opens, the right plate of C2 is nearly equals 14V, and the left plate of C2 is 5.6V which means the voltage on C2 is 9.4V.  when IL = Isat makes the right plate of C2 equals 0V and the left plate of C2 is -9.4V because the voltage on a capacitor cant change suddenly.

Answer (score 2):

The “spot the misteaks” link is quite detailed just as the designer has constraints on operating conditions and values and has poor margin with faults, so too does the critic.   When C1, C2 are small enough ~<10nF then C2 has the biggest effect on frequency, also by load R , Rz, and LC components.

It is has a small window margin for value ratios to get  stable instabilities as an oscillator. At some point during startup, it’s “[chaos](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgDCCsB0Z-DEBYCmBaAHOaBmATAIwF4DsYkSOBkOkAbNSJSAREnlOkQFAAuIeegLxIQOHHWGiIBEGjrQ6%20OhnZ12OMpEjYcSMHnwYAnHUJgSkDBLEwOAExQAzAIYBXADa9uAdyZwWPCx9GToIMG4AJRYSSWIsAliQDHDwf0C08OhIXyZ8MTw2UwLw7gAnJmLBSSRinDBpEDDYQW4AczEbfAhxSV7M7gB5SslqqCRRMdK-RL7CgSFu8FyxvBEF0aEIgGMNvbGltmgkenQsGAk6WNiMEk1IYxJZMFgwAm5d%20smhVa2WY7gGDCiAQBDO-3UYW0JBIxhoMIY2Dg712lA4pA4aLEDUyrzexgJhKJxPOsBwjww8XiZAsOheyPKMTiQSZezYZEZ-VmnVGYCwEAYOGgxkZWK%20eQ4h2w7w8-ggYyxUyR8GJquJcnpSFuIjwdCUxhSJz1y3scpKZtWIEcrk83j0IAAXigAHYoMpoGAkFj-J6USBBAjGAPwPDoL3yvEgxCqKDQL3vB2spbcy1O13uz25ELmsXzCJ%20foYiUCEgcfOs%20I8wIJXJclnZyvl-pLbOHLMBQOYgKrWs2EQ9PtbXIpn6j0ZZ-IKqo-FaLebNvO9zZ9Pul5Z%20RVCRVr8u1OZFPo4iIVLlJOv8lgIbj6HBMLUsCZQJKFC%20GAD6SDfYDfBFolBwP7fgon7fngb7vjg15gLeEzBOcSREGWAgASBP6CBQ4EELgQZapA0FkHQNBKF%20eIEF%204HgQBkH8KeNQdkkEBoLISDCkCepvIa6h8sYGp4pABBKP6ZiELCSgYAkATWu4XiMmsogCfKa4KWk7wFjiCrdkOAD2TRNI0v4UPakj0vAWoYAGggqdwOmTCA8ZXMYSDGaRypvN6shYZApZ8vxiROf6OogAAClpbjeDpHCyPGf44PyLkmW5kWVLAgYEoY7BgGEhSSEFACWzrWWItnxrE5LSPFLm3rIQphHqgp8jChhWF6QXQAAOgAzgADs6XWFQJAh2UyZWuc8LnyUiMLGGApgULcbwWIRwWdfYuVaY43CxUwKndtkIAADJaS49ibRJKlcB5kZRqCYYgAAwk4ABGp0sLeMjvQEkRPS9jBZAgaoAzxJmyAAks69huNsvAuM62woC9QMsOgPFgmgXp3Q6L2pKwl4QAAQig0MAPQABYAGIAKLcEAA)”. (Not optimized)

Efficiency is better than an LDO but every part must be critically chosen to get the right instability to oscillate well.  Yet under some conditions , self destructive.

The common base feedback ends up with a large current spike depending on DCR and ESR that can be as much as 10x the rated current for 1% duty cycle while the diode switch can be 50% d.c. if you don’t choose the “right values”.  Everything is interactive with the load R so (in/) stability on startup is different from steady-state for optimum values.

The driver R must be small enough to saturate the PNP with 10% hFE R.load min to work.